# cómo puedo hacer un return View(); con JavaScript? ASP.NET CORE MVC RRS feed

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Nueva consulta, cómo puedo hacer un return View, cuando se acepte el mensaje: alert('Photo captured')

```
    <script language="JavaScript">
        function take_snapshot() {
            Webcam.snap(function (data_uri) {
                document.getElementById('results').innerHTML =
                    '<img src="' +
                    data_uri +
                    '"/>';
                Webcam.upload(data_uri,
                    'Capture?coduser=' + document.getElementById('coduser').value,
                    function (code, text) {
                        alert('Photo captured');//mensaje de completado
                    });
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucioné, este es el codigo para hacer `return View` en Javascript.

```
location.href = '/Ejemplo/Sitio';
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: En que parte de la función pones eso?

Comment: Hola Jorge, las respuesta que son solo código, son consideradas de baja calidad, te sugiero que edites la tuya, y expliques de que forma resuelve el problema planteado, así podrás ayudar a otros que tengan el mismo problema, y evitarás que sea cerrada y/o recibir votos negativos.